# NoSuchFieldError: RESOURCE_PREFIX when using Tess4J with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I've tried using Tess4J in Eclipse but it results with the error in the title. I imported these jar files: tess4j, jai_imageio, and jna. The test code I have written is as per the example given on their examples page.

```
                File DMTfile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\DMTcap.bmp");
                BufferedImage DMTcap = ImageIO.read(DMTfile);Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();

                String result = "";
                try {
                    result = instance.doOCR(DMTcap);
                } catch (TesseractException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(result);
```

The full error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RESOURCE_PREFIX
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at DMT$10.actionPerformed(DMT.java:516)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Platform.RESOURCE_PREFIX`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/Platform.java) is a JNA constant. Make sure you use the appropriate version of JNA (4.1.0).

Also check out the answers in this post: [NoSuchFieldError: RESOURCE_PREFIX with a maven project using tess4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307976/nosuchfielderror-resource-prefix-with-a-maven-project-using-tess4j)

Comment: Is this the right quote directed towards my problem? "2/ tess4j had a transitive dependancy toward com.sun.jna:jna:jar:3.0.9 conflicting with net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.1.0 (also from tess4j) ecluding the 3.0.9 version makes everything work, the RESSOURCE_PREFIX error was coming from that" I made sure my JNA library was 4.1.0 and downloaded directly from the maven site. When Sliders_Alpha states that I need to remove the 3.0.9 version what does that mean?

Comment: Probably somewhere in your setup, it includes two `jna.jar`, both of which contains `com.sun.jna.Platform` class, but one does not have `RESOURCE_PREFIX` constant. Try to determine and keep the one that supports `RESOURCE_PREFIX` and exclude the other one.

Comment: Thank you! I realized JHook.jar had JNA in it as well. This answered my problem by removing the extra JNA.jar